# Replacing Node's native Promises with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Is there a way to replace the native Promise constructor in Node.js without doing it on a per-file basis (so that third-party libraries will also use it)?

The following does not work:

```
global.Promise = require('bluebird');

const foo = (cb) => cb('hello');

Promise.fromCallback(cb => foo(cb)) // TypeError: Promise.fromCallback is not a function
  .tap(val => console.log(val))
  .then(val => { console.log('fromCallback is supported!') });
```

Comment: It seems to work for me, I just had to change `foo` to `cb(null, 'hello')`

Comment: Possibly Related: [May I use global.Promise=require("bluebird")](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1026).

Comment: Also possibly related: [bluebird 3.0: how to use it as overload for global Promise?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10801)